# How to populate <SelectInput> choices with already fetched data

Tags: reactjs, redux, admin-on-rest

In my App component I have a subscriptions Resource with an edit component:

```
<Resource name="subscriptions" list={SubscriptionList} edit={SubscriptionEdit} />
```

SubscriptionEdit looks something like this:

```
 export const SubscriptionEdit = props => (
  <Edit title={<SubscriptionTitle />} {...props}>
    <TabbedForm >
      <FormTab label="Info">
        ...

        <SelectInput
          source="typeSubscription"
          choices={[
            { id: 'monthly', name: 'Monthly' },
            { id: 'anual', name: 'Anual' },
          ]}
          label="Subscription plan"
        />
      </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

And the data fetched from the endpoint when you enter this view is a JSON like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  typeSubscription: null,
  selectedDay: null,
  daysAvailable: [
      { id: '07-01-2018', name: 'First day` },
      { id: '07-03-2018', name: 'Second day` },
      { id: '07-07-2018', name: 'Third day` },
      { id: '07-08-2018', name: 'Fourth day` },
  ],
}
```

What I need to do is add another SelectInput using daysAvailable array for the choices, in order to select the day for 'selectedDay'.

```
<SelectInput
      source="selectedDay"
      choices={NEED TO ADD daysAvailable HERE!}
      label="Select an available day"
 />
```

This data is already available in the store and in the record prop, but I can't figure out how to properly use it in choices. Trying to use it directly like a prop results in different errors and I think thas is normal because I'm messing with the inners of redux and admin-on-rest.

I tried to use ReferenceInput and leave choices for SelectInput empty as the docs suggested, but as this list of days changes based on the ID of the user I couldn't find a way to add this parameter to the new Resource.

I'm using admin-on-rest but planning to upgrade to react-admin in the near future if that's relevant.

That said, any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is what [ReferenceInput](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md#referenceinput) is for. You can supply the name of the resource, like this:

```
import { ReferenceInput, SelectInput } from 'react-admin'

<ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
    <SelectInput optionText="title" />
</ReferenceInput>
```